# Import data from Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I retrieve keyword IDs and clicks from a Google ads account and type them into Google sheets.
In Google sheets, I do some calculations before I want to pull keyword ID back to Google ads.

How do I do it?

```
function main() {

  //Step 1: Connect Google Ads to the Google Sheet
  var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('data');
  ss.clear();

 //Step 2: Create an array to store the data
  var sheetarray = [['clicks', 'ID']];

  //Step 3: Collect the data you need
  var keywords = AdsApp.keywords()
      .withCondition("Clicks > 0")
      .forDateRange("LAST_7_DAYS")
      .get();
  
  //Step 4: Add the data you got from Google Ads into the array
while (keywords.hasNext()) {
  var keyword = keywords.next();
  sheetarray.push([
      keyword.getStatsFor("LAST_7_DAYS").getClicks(),
      keyword.getId(),
    ]);
}

   
  //Step 5: Display the contents of the array
  Logger.log(sheetarray);
  if (sheetarray.length > 0) {
     
    // Step 6: Send the array's data to the Google Sheet
    ss.getRange(1, 1, sheetarray.length, sheetarray[0].length).setValues(sheetarray);
  }
  

  //Step 6: Get keyword IDs from the sheets but how??
  
  
   
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to replicate your code if you can provide the content of `sheetarray`  or at least an example of it and what structure you want the keyword ID to be stored.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being unclear. 

The first part of the script retrieves data in the "data1_export" tab here:


https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NHTJusSD_AafDYYevFN6SZmWrT3KBh8fw7G0VEQmFaI/edit?usp=sharing

Then I would like to get the data from "data2_import" back again where I need an array with all IDs from "data2_import" sheets.

How do I make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
var keyword_IDs = ss.getRange(2, 2, sheetarray.length-1, 1).getValues().flat();
```

Probably

---

> *flat() does not work, but join() does*

I don't know what you're trying to get. But it looks a bit wrong. `flat()` and `join()` have very different output. `flat()` returns `Array`. `join()` returns `String`

```
var keyword_IDs = ss.getRange(2, 2, sheetarray_length-1, 1).getValues().flat();

Logger.log(keyword_IDs)                            // [id1, id2, id3, id4, id5]
Logger.log(keyword_IDs.constructor.name);          // Array
Logger.log(keyword_IDs.filter(x => x==",").length) // 0.0 -- it has no comas

var keyword_IDs = ss.getRange(2, 2, sheetarray_length-1, 1).getValues().join();

Logger.log(keyword_IDs);                           // "id1,id2,id3,id4,id5"
Logger.log(keyword_IDs.constructor.name);          // String
Logger.log(keyword_IDs.match(/,/g).length)         // 4.0 -- it has four comas
```

> *I get the error: TypeError: Cannot find function map in object ''' var CampaignExact = AdsApp.campaigns().withCondition(Campaign_Exact).get().next(); var keywords = CampaignExact.keywords().withIds(keyword_ID).get(); while(keywords.hasNext()) { var keyword = keywords.next(); keyword.pause(); } '''*

It's almost indecipherable message. Sorry.

The error says about `map()` function. But I see no `map()` in your code. Nevertheless `map()` is a Array's method. Not String's.

So I guess `withIds(keyword_ID)` don't work since `keyword_ID` is a String like this `'id1,id2,id3...'`. Probably there should be an array `keywords_ID` (`['id1', 'id2', 'id3', ...]`) and then there should be `keyword_ID = keywords_ID[0]` or `keyword_ID = keywords_ID[1]` ...etc somewhere above. Just a guess.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: By my observations there are 99 chances from 100 we will never see the author of this question in this thread. And we will never know what the problem was there. It never ceases to amaze me how many weird and/or ungrateful persons ask questions here.

Comment: flat() does not work, but join() does.
var keyword_ID = ss_get.getRange(2, 1, sheetarray.length-1, 1).getValues().join();

But how can I pause keyword IDs from the from the campaign:

With the code below I get the error:
TypeError: Cannot find function map in object

'''
var CampaignExact = AdsApp.campaigns().withCondition(Campaign_Exact).get().next();
 
    var keywords = CampaignExact.keywords().withIds(keyword_ID).get();
    while(keywords.hasNext()) {
     var keyword = keywords.next();
     keyword.pause();
    }
'''